# Does “semper una ad astra” translate to “forever as one to the stars”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I’m trying to translate “forever as one to the stars” for the purpose of engraving in rings for me and my partner. My attempt is “semper una ad astra” — is this close? What changes would you recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would indeed accept this translation.
Notice that “semper” is rather translated as “always” than “forever”. If you would rather express “forever“ as “until we die”, I’d may suggest:

> In perpetuum una ad astra.

You could also say:

> In aeternum una ad astra

These expressions are more similar to “forever”. However, I’d say that “semper” in the original sentence is fine, too.